# Getting Webkit to pay attention to <legend> margins

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I'm simply trying to get Chrome/Safari to pay attention when I say `margin-bottom: 20px` on a `<legend>` tag...

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HNZWK/

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Foo</legend>
    <div>Bar</div>
</fieldset>

legend {
    margin        : 0 0 20px 0;
    display       : block;
    position      : relative;
    border-bottom : 1px solid #000;
}
```

I can't seem to "detach" the legend from the fieldset.  The div below is bumped to below the height of the legend (can be seen by messing with the legend height in css), but it's ignoring the bottom margin.

Any ideas?  Every other browser plays nice here...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Solved by using `-webkit-margin-collapse` and `margin-top` automatically on the first thing to follow the `legend` (in this example, the `div`):

http://jsfiddle.net/HNZWK/5/

```
legend {
    margin-bottom : 20px;
}

legend + * {
    -webkit-margin-top-collapse : separate;
    margin-top                  : 20px;
}
```

Comment: only semi-fix, what if your first element is afloat? --> http://jsfiddle.net/HNZWK/55/

Comment: No, it's a complete fix for the problem I had, you just have a different issue :)  I'd suggest posting a new question on here since this one is a year old.  Reference this one so people have a starting point.

Comment: I had to style legend { margin-bottom: 0 } so that I didn't get a 40px margin total.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of browsers seem to have issues with the legend element. My suggest is take the text you put in the legend element and wrap that in a span. Then apply all your styling to that span.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same thing here in Safari.

Perhaps you can use padding instead.  That seems to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/HNZWK/3/

Comment: Can't use padding because I have a bottom-border :(

Comment: @cwolves: This seems to be a Webkit issue with how it interprets margins in this situation.  Not sure how else you could get around it.

Comment: @cwolves:  Then why not apply a top margin to the div immediately under the Legend instead?  **EDIT:**  This does not work... looks like Webkit ignores Legend here too.